# How to fetch a custom configuration yaml file from within a bundle in Symfony 4.1?

Tags: php, symfony, config, symfony4

I am creating a bundle that provides some common functionality for our applications. From services inside the bundle, I want to load a custom configuration file -- NOT the default package config override file.

For example, in the bundle's `Resources/config/error_codes.yml` I will have some default error codes. The developers using this package should be able to create their own `error_codes.yml` in their config that *adds* new error codes.

How do I locate, fetch and combine the two `error_codes.yml` files?

Comment: Basically you don't.  Your default error codes will be defined in your DependencyInjection\Configuration class.  Additional error codes defined at the application level would then be merged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override configuration file.

But you can create configuration tree with default values (see [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html)) and define custom values outside a bundle. 
Another way is usage parameters inside bundle, a parameter can be easy changed in any place.

And finally, for some special cases you can override everything via [Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html)

Comment: If I can't override the config file, then at the very least I want the user of the bundle to just create his own config file, which I use from within the bundle. Assuming they create `config/error_codes.yml`, how do I load it from within the bundle? It's not clear.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower Have you checked the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html)?

Comment: @Cerad it doesn't mention how to use a custom-named config file -- only the default package config file.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower Which is basically the point.  There is no built in support for a custom named config file.  Just does not work that way.  I suppose if you really really really wanted to you could have your Configuration file load in a yaml file and build your tree from it.